# Female hunter/explorer with ginger hair in pigtails who poses as a demon in a demon school

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm trying to find an old manga. All I remember is the main character was a female with ginger hair that was in pigtails. She was a hunter/explorer and she ends up in a demon school pretending to be a demon I believe. She can use magic but I believe some of the demons know her secret.

Comment: Probably not Pippi Longstocking.